# Trouble with least squares in Python

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

I am working on a project analyzing data and am trying to use a least squares method (built-in) to do so. I found a tutorial that provided code as an example and it works fine:

```
x = arange(0, 6e-2, 6e-2/30)
A, k, theta = 10, 1.0/3e-2, pi/6
y_true = A*sin(2*pi*k*x+theta)
y_meas = y_true+2*random.randn(len(x))

def residuals(p, y, x):
    A, k, theta = p
    print "A type" + str(type(A))
    print "k type" + str(type(k))
    print "theta type" + str(type(theta))
    print "x type" + str(type(x))
    err = y - A*sin(2*pi*k*x+theta)
    return err

def peval(x, p):
    return p[0]*sin(2*pi*p[1]*x+p[2])

p0 = [8,1/2.3e-2,pi/3]

plsq = leastsq(residuals, p0, args=(y_meas, x))
print(plsq[0])
```

However, when I try transferring this to my own code, it keeps throwing errors. I have been working on this for a while and have managed to eliminate, I think, all of the type mismatch issues which plagued me early on. As far as I can tell, currently the two pieces of code are nearly identical but I am getting the error
'unsupported operand type(s)' and can't figure out what to do next. Here is the section of my code that pertains to this question my code:

```
if (ls is not None):
        from scipy.optimize import leastsq
        p0 = [8, 1/2.3e-2,pi/3]
        def residuals(p, y, x):
            A,k,theta = p
            if (type(x) is list):
                x = asarray(x)
            err = y - A*sin(2*pi*k*x+theta) #Point of error
            return err
        def peval(x, p):
            return p[0]*sin(2*pi*p[1]*x+p[2])
        plsq = leastsq(residuals, p0, args=(listRelativeCount, listTime))
        plsq_0 = peval(listTime, plsq[0])
```

Where listTime is the x-values of the data found in listRelativeCount. I have marked the line where the code is currently failing. Any help would be appreciated as I have been stuck on this problem for over a month.

Comment: Is `listRelativeCount` a list?

Comment: Could you please include the full traceback?

Comment: Can you give sample data for `residuals`, `listRelativeCount` and `listTime`?

Answer (score 2):

Three things are happening in the line you called `#Point of error`:  You are multiplying values, adding values and applying the `sin()` function.  "Unsupported operand type" means something is wrong in one of these operations.  It means you need to verify the types of the operands, and also make sure you know what function is being applied.

- Are you sure you know the types (and `dtype`s, for `ndarray`s) of all the operands, including `pi`, `x`, `theta` and `A`?
- Are you sure which `sin` function you are using?  `math.sin` is not the same as `np.sin`, and they accept different operands.
- Mulitplying a list by a scalar (if your `listTime` variable is really a list) does something completely different from multiplying scalar and `ndarray`.

If it's unclear which operation is causing the error, try breaking up the expression:

```
err1 = 2*pi*k
err2 = err1*x
err3 = err2 +  theta
err4 = sin(err3)
err5 = A*err4
err = y - err5
```

This ought to clarify what operation throws the exception.

This is an example of why it's often a better idea to use explicit package names, like `np.sin()` rather than `sin()`.

Comment: I have checked the types of all the data I am using and x is an ndarray and everything else you see is a numpy.float64 . I have retried the code making sure to explicitly use the numpy sin and I am still getting the same result. The traceback reads:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\~~~~~~~~~~", line 66, in residuals
    err = y - A*np.sin(2*pi*k*x+theta)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'numpy.float64' and 'numpy.ndarray'

edited for length

Comment: The next thing I'd try, since you have a line number for the error, is to break up the expression into single-operation expressions, and see which line produces the error.  I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I broke it up into individual expressions and it doesn't like multiplying x (an ndarray) by k (a numpy.float64, but what confuses me is that the same error does not appear in the example and I don't see what the difference is between the two of them. It seems to me as if the example is recalculating err for each value in x.

Comment: The next place I would look is to check the scope of `x` and `k`.  When you check `type(k)`, for example, it might not be the same `k` as what the function is multiplying.  Two simple things to try out:  Try changing the names of the variables, or try explicit `global` declarations (if that is how you intended to manage the variables).

Comment: I have made all the variables global just like in the example and have moved the associated functions outside of the main function so that they have a global scope as well. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Also, I just thought that one big difference between these two problems is that in my case the numbers are very small whereas in the example they are "normal" sized. Could that be causing a problem, and if so how do I fix it?

Comment: I noticed in your post where you pasted the error that the formula is not correct. Maybe there's an issue in pasting, but this is not correct: `Anp.sin(2*pik*x+theta)`. Should be: `A*np.sin(2*np.pi*k*x+theta)`